# Disable html required tag in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

i need to disable the required tag of this textbox when a submit button is click

```
 <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="username" required name="username" type="text" placeholder="myusername"/>
```

i tried to write the following code but it did not work

```
  Dim tbUserName As TextBox =Page.FindControl("username") 
 tbUserName.required = False
```

can you please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `required` is not part of the ASP.NET TextBox control's properties, thus there is no server-side property equivalent.

You can use the following to remove it:

```
username.Attributes.Remove("required")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 tbUserName.Enabled = False
```

Also, "Required" isn't a valid propert for the Textbox control. ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`required` is client-side attribute which does not have direct equivalent on server-side.

You can try

```
username.Attributes("required") = "false"
```

this works when you're already on the server. If you need to do this on client - handle form's `onsubmit` event and do something like

```
$get('username').setAttribute('required', 'false');
```

Of course the easiest way would be simple remove that attribute from textbox markup.